# Noir setting jobs/professions that we don't see much

Tags: society, culture

On a noir setting I'm working on I'm trying to think of other jobs I could give my characters that aren't the classic ones like "the detective", "the cop" or(as it seems to be the case with most female characters) "the dame that might be a singer or spy or just a regular damsel in distress".

I want my characters to be able to interact with many parts of a society, but also be able to enter into trouble or have to deal with the danger.I want to give a focus on their relationships, to those around them and what happens in this town when the detectives/cops are not the ones investigating.
So basically:

-It is a noir setting(this one is a mix of the 20s, WWII, Cold War and some anachronisms here and there).Black, gray, white are predominant but there are certain colors that can appear(as mark of something out of ordinary) in certain characters or places.

-What the characters are and who they are in society plays a hand at what they can do, what/who they have access to and how society sees them.It also works as hooks for their adventures and the kind of stuff they get up to.

-If possible give me what would be considered a "man's", a "woman's" and a "unisex" kind of jobs.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! As it stands, the question needs more focus; we generally don't do open ended lists. You may want to take the [tour] to become acquainted with the purpose and conventions of this site. (And, honestly, it's not as if it is hard to find what men and women did in the 1930s. Note that during the war very many women [took up positions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosie_the_Riveter) which before the war would have been considered a male preserve. Also note that the world is a very diverse place; American and Soviet women did not live the same kind of life.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Thinking of persons who might be investigating, but not be cops:**

1. **Reporter**.  That can be a man or a woman (Lois Lane!).  Reporters go all over the place and get into all kinds of trouble.
2. **Mob enforcer**. This is probably going to be a man.  It would make an interesting character.  The enforcer makes sure his boss is getting his due, and if something looks fishy he will investigate.
3. **Civil servant**.  Persons associated with city hall might investigate as part of their jobs.  They might be making sure codes and rules are followed.  They might be looking for a bribe.  Men and women can be civil servants.
4. **Ragpicker**. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragpicker

> Ragpicker, or chiffonnier, is a term for someone who makes a living by
>   rummaging through refuse in the streets to collect material for
>   salvage. Scraps of cloth and paper could be turned into cardboard,
>   broken glass could be melted down and reused, and even dead cats and
>   dogs could be skinned to make clothes.
>
> Although it was solely a job for the lowest of the working classes,
>   ragpicking was considered an honest occupation, more on the level of
>   street sweeper than of a beggar...Modern sanitation and recycling
>   programs ultimately caused the profession to decline, though it did
>   not disappear entirely; rag and bone men were still operating in the
>   1970s.

There is a can man in my neighborhood.  He works hard.  He goes all over and people know why - he is looking for cans.  This could be a man or a woman.

5. **Kid.**   Kids are kept inside these days because video games need to be played.  In older times kids wandered around and got into things.  It was expected.  Curious kids might investigate.

I can totally imagine all 5 of these characters in a film noir.  The reporter and the ragpicker know each other from way back and have an old working relationship.  Reporter and enforcer wind up unlikely allies and they have chemistry.  Civil servant on the take is jerk and is going to wind up dead.  Brother and sister kid move story along because they know what is up.

Comment: I would add the following  to the list above (1-5) of occupations in which the person can be noirish:  doctor, nurse, undertaker, mortician, undertaker, grave-digger, forensic scientist. @Willk